# Python getting subsets

Tags: python

```
def subsets(arr):
    n = len(arr)
    if n == 0:
        return [[]]

    els_except_last = arr[:n-1]
    last_el = arr[n-1]

    working_sets = subsets(els_except_last)

    new_sets = working_sets[:]
    for s in new_sets:
        s.append(last_el)

    # HERE: both new_sets and working_sets are modified

    result = [new_sets, working_sets]

    return result
```

Can someone explain exactly why `new_sets` and `working_sets` are both modified when I only intend to modify the elements inside `new_sets`? Is it because the elements inside the arrays are also arrays, and they are shallowly copied? If that's the case, should I really use `deepcopy()` or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What should `subsets()` return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Is it because the elements inside the arrays are also arrays, and they are shallowly copied?*

Yes.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html

> The difference between shallow and deep copying is only relevant for compound objects (objects that contain other objects, like lists or class instances):
>
> A shallow copy constructs a new compound object and then (to the extent possible) inserts **references** into it to the objects found in the original.
>
> A deep copy constructs a new compound object and then, **recursively**, inserts copies into it of the objects found in the original.

*(emphasis mine)*

You just made fresh copies of 2nd level references. You need to perform a copy on each level, hence the recursion in deep copy is important.

You can play around with the below code ([live](http://ideone.com/P5G0c3)):

```
import copy
last_el = 0
working_sets = [[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]]
#new_sets = copy.deepcopy(working_sets)
new_sets = working_sets[:]
for s in new_sets:
    print(id(s))
for s in working_sets:
    print(id(s))
    
for s in new_sets:
    s.append(last_el)
    
print(new_sets)
print(working_sets)
```